# Cassandra - How to execute Solr query on UDT with map<text, uuid>

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax

I have the following database structure:

```
CREATE TYPE udt_category_subcategory
{
   category     map<text, uuid>,
   subcategory  map<text, uuid>
}

CREATE TABLE fenix
{
   id        uuid,
   category  frozen<udt_category_subcategory>
}

CREATE SEARCH INDEX ON fenix WITH COLUMNS category;
```

I need to perform a search in the `Category` field of the `Fenix` ​​table using `Solr`, in this field I have the following data structure saved:

```
{
    "category" : {
        "Category Name 1" : "d8f00199-7103-476f-9527-f7d4c92d55f5"
    },
    "subcategory" : {
        "Subcategory Name 1" : "06cd6a42-4c50-46ed-a97a-1854c50a7e6f"
    }
}
```

I'm trying the following instruction:

```
SELECT * FROM fenix WHERE solr_query = '{!tuple}category.subcategory:06cd6a42-4c50-46ed-a97a-1854c50a7e6f'
```

Obviously this filter is not working currently, but, what is wrong? I need to enter the "key" field of `map <text, uuid>` column to work? It's possible? This data structure make sense for this type of search?

Any help are welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

in DSE Search map columns are used to hold dynamic fields:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/cql/cql/cql_using/search_index/addMapField.html

So you need to query it as if it was a dynamic field:

```
SELECT * FROM fenix WHERE solr_query = '{!tuple}category.subcategory_Name_1:06cd6a42-4c50-46ed-a97a-1854c50a7e6f'
```

Please notice I have removed spaces from the map key and made the map key match the map field name for the dyn field prefix. If you read about dyn fields in DSE Search you will understand it.

TL;DR: Query it as `{!tuple}udt.dynamicfield:value`